# Virtualizing treelistview?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

Does anyone know of a good way to display hierarchical data with columns?

It has to be virtualizing, as it must be able to handle several million records.

It should also be multi-select, most treeview controls are not.

Winforms preferred, but will ElementHost WPF if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear what you mean about hierarchical data with columns, can you clarify? One possibility is the new WPF DataGrid. Depending on the functionality you're looking for it *may* be what you're looking for.

The bits for datagrid are available on codeplex:
http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14963

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Infragistics UltraWinGrid, here's a video that demos some features:
http://www.infragistics.com/howto/wingrid.aspx